# Keeping Pro and Lite Version on Different Branches

Tags: objective-c, xcode, git, github

I have a pro version and a lite version of the app that have nearly identical codebases. The difference being that the lite version has ads in various view controllers as well as in app purchases. I have each version on its own branch in Git with the lite version being the master branch currently.

I have localized the pro version, switched all strings to NSLocalized string, added localization files etc. I am wondering what the best way to merge these changes into the lite version without overwriting the differences between the two. When I open a "merge into..." session in Xcode, it automatically would overwrite the differences.

Is there a way to skip a block of code in a merge?

There may not be a solution for this but before I do it manually, I just wanted to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a git problem but a project structure problem. You should never have tried to misuse git branches for this purpose to start with. Instead, you should have used Xcode's project / workspace facilities (or a framework) to organize *the code itself* so that it could be shared between two *targets*.